# Mongodb query for ObjectID returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, npm

The following method should query in the conversationCollection for an entry with a given ObjectID.

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
const ObjectID = mongodb.ObjectID


app.get('/getConversations', (req, res) => {
    verifyUser(req, res, function(result) {
        if(result !== "false") {
            for(var i=0; i<result.conversations.length; i++) {
                var objectid = new ObjectID(result.conversations[i].toString())
                conversationCollection.findOne({_id: objectid}, function(res2) {
                    console.log(res2.members)
                    res.end(res2)
                })
            }
        } else {
            res.end("Error")
        }
    })
})
```

The result object has e.g. following data:

```
{ 
  // ...
  conversations: [ 5ccdc51d22399918b45b33d4,
                   5ccdc52322399918b45b33d6 ],
  // ...
}
```

The problem is that `console.log(res2.members)` always throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of null`. The query for the findOne-method seams to be wrong. I've tried some variants already:

```
conversationCollection.findOne({"_id": objectid}, function(res2)
conversationCollection.findOne({_id: new ObjectID(result.conversations[i].toString())}, function(res2)
conversationCollection.findOne({"_id": ew ObjectID(result.conversations[i])}, function(res2)
conversationCollection.findOne({"_id": result.conversations[i]}, function(res2)
```

Nothing works and every variant produces the same nullpointer-exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the res2 holds error data which is null.
findOne function has two params in callback: 1st is error and other is data. either of them is null.

try this:

```
app.get('/getConversations', (req, res) => {
    verifyUser(req, res, function(result) {
        if(result !== "false") {
            for(var i=0; i<result.conversations.length; i++) {
                var objectid = new ObjectID(result.conversations[i].toString())
                conversationCollection.findOne({_id: objectid}, function(err,res2) {
                    console.log(err)
                    console.log(res2.members)
                    res.end(res2)
                })
            }
        } else {
            res.end("Error")
        }
    })
})
```